# How can this Postgres function deadlock?

Tags: postgresql, concurrency, locking, deadlock, blocking

Our postgres database is reporting a lot of deadlocks on tuples in a relation.
There are only two functions that use the relation and usually only one of the functions is involved in the deadlocks.

The function that most commonly causes the deadlocks has two queries:

```
1. The first query 
        looks for ONE photo 
        and ROW LOCKS ALL the photo rows 
        for ALL albums the the photo is found in

    For example given the below table of data:
           if the query was looking for Photo 2 
           then it would LOCK ALL 6 rows of Album A and C. 

            album   photo   version
            A       1       1.0     lock
            A       2       1.0     lock    update
            A       3       1.0     lock
            B       8       2.0
            B       9       2.0
            C       1       1.1     lock
            C       2       1.1     lock    update
            C       5       1.1     lock
            D       7       4.0
            D       8       4.0

2. The second query then updates the 2 tuples for Photo 2.
```

The FOR UPDATE and UPDATE query access the tuples in the same order using the below queries.

From what I understand if the tuples are always accessed in Album and Photo order then a deadlock should not be possible.

The function is called many times a second and I did anticipate that blocking would occur but at a loss to explain the deadlocks.

Any help is appreciated.

Queries in the Function 'album_version_set'

```
    PERFORM 1
    FROM work.album a
    WHERE EXISTS (  
        SELECT 
            x.album
        FROM work.album x
        WHERE 
            x.photo = 2
            AND x.album = a.album)
    ORDER BY 
        a.album, 
        a.photo
    FOR UPDATE;


    WITH cte_update_version (album) AS (
        UPDATE work.album a
        SET 
            version = version + .1 
        FROM (
            SELECT 
                x.album,
                x.photo
            FROM work.album x
            WHERE
                x.photo = 2
            ORDER BY 
                x.album
                x.photo
            ) ord 
        WHERE 
            a.album = ord.album
            AND a.photo = ord.photo
        RETURNING 
            a.album)
    INSERT INTO tmp_album_keys(
        album)
    SELECT DISTINCT
        us.album
    FROM 
        cte_update_version;
```

---

Adding more to this question:

From the error logs I can tell that the function 'album_version_set' is conflicting with itself and causing the deadlock.

Below is the entry from the log.  It seems the log only shows the statements from 1 of the processes involved in the deadlock.  Since this function has two queries I'm not sure which query in process 31019 is part of the deadlock.

Here is an entry from the log:

```
2018-03-06 15:35:20 UTC:10.1.2.1(43636):z1login@atier:[31024]:ERROR:  deadlock detected
2018-03-06 15:35:20 UTC:10.1.2.1(43636):z1login@atier:[31024]:DETAIL:  Process 31024 waits for ShareLock on transaction 8334317; blocked by process 31019.
    Process 31019 waits for ShareLock on transaction 8334322; blocked by process 31024.
    Process 31024: SELECT * FROM album_version_set($1, $2)
    Process 31019: SELECT * FROM album_version_set($1, $2)
2018-03-06 15:35:20 UTC:10.1.2.1(43636):z1login@atier:[31024]:HINT:  See server log for query details.
2018-03-06 15:35:20 UTC:10.1.2.1(43636):z1login@atier:[31024]:CONTEXT:  while locking tuple (11,83) in relation "album"
    SQL statement "SELECT 1
                    FROM work.album a
                    WHERE EXISTS (  
                        SELECT 
                            x.album
                        FROM work.album x
                        WHERE 
                            x.photo = 2
                            AND x.album = a.album)
                    ORDER BY 
                        a.album, 
                        a.photo
                    FOR UPDATE;"
    PL/pgSQL function album_version_set(character varying,smallint) line 69 at PERFORM
2018-03-06 15:35:20 UTC:10.1.2.1(43636):z1login@atier:[31024]:STATEMENT:  SELECT * FROM album_version_set($1, $2)
```

Comment: made a fiddle for that (where we cannot tests parallel runs AFAIK) http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/c0481/4 , had to fix the last from in second query (cte_update_status) and the fir column in the update subquery (album_key). Can you check that this wrong `cte_update_status` is not a real thing ?

Comment: Look into the log to see which two statements are clashing. That might help.

Comment: This could certainly deadlock (assuming you're at the default [isolation level](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/transaction-iso.html)) if someone else is inserting rows while the function is running, since your locking query and your `UPDATE` statement see different snapshots of the table. Is this a possibility?

Comment: @regilero Thanks for taking a look at this.  I am using a simplified version of the actual function and didn't see the errors you caught.  I fixed the errors so it's more clear for others, thanks.

Comment: @NickBarnes We are using the default, ReadCommitted isolation level.  All rows for an album are inserted in one transaction.  Once records are inserted then only the version column is updated.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe From the logs I can tell that the function is conflicting with itself.  I added an entry from the log to the question if you care to take a look at it.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Can you also append `EXPLAIN` output for both queries? Maybe seeing what PostgreSQL actually does will give us a clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there's at least one race condition in there with the potential for a deadlock (at the default [transaction isolation level](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/transaction-iso.html), anyway), though I can't say for sure that it's causing yours.

Say your table initially looks like this:

```
album   photo   version
B       2       1.0
C       2       1.0
```

Your first query runs, and begins locking rows.

Meanwhile, someone else runs an `INSERT INTO work.album VALUES ('A', 2, 1.0)`.

This new row is ignored by the `FOR UPDATE` query (as its snapshot of the database is fixed at the start of the statement), but it's still picked up by the subsequent `UPDATE`, and is locked in the process.

Overall, the locking order within your transaction (in terms of `album` values) is `'B'`, `'C'`, `'A'`; you are now at risk of a deadlock.

Worse than that, if the concurrent insert contains multiple rows, then you've updated the record with `photo = 2` without locking the rest of the album. For example, if the concurrent statement were `INSERT INTO work.album VALUES ('A', 2, 1.0), ('A', 3, 1.0)`, then you'd be left in the following state:

```
album   photo   version
A       2       1.0             update
A       3       1.0     
B       2       1.0     lock    update
C       2       1.0     lock    update
```

In general, repeating the same `WHERE` conditions in your `FOR UPDATE` query and in your `UPDATE` statement leaves you vulnerable to these kinds of deadlocks. A general pattern for avoiding this problem is to have your locking query return some unambiguous row identifier (a generated primary key if you have one, or failing that, the [`ctid`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-system-columns.html)*) to make it clear exactly what has been locked, and then pass these identifiers along to the `UPDATE` statement to ensure that it targets only the locked tuples, e.g.:

```
DECLARE
  locked_tuples tid[];
BEGIN
  locked_tuples := ARRAY(
    SELECT ctid
    FROM work.album
    WHERE album IN (
      SELECT x.album
      FROM work.album x
      WHERE x.photo = 2
    )
    ORDER BY album, photo
    FOR UPDATE
  );

  WITH cte_update_version (album) AS (
    UPDATE work.album
    SET version = version + .1 
    WHERE 
      ctid = ANY(locked_tuples) AND
      photo = 2
    RETURNING album
  )
  INSERT INTO tmp_album_keys(album)
  SELECT DISTINCT album
  FROM cte_update_status;
END
```

This should eliminate the possibility of deadlock, though it also means that the concurrently inserted row will no longer be updated (which may or may not be what you were hoping for).

---

* Be careful with `ctid` values. They can't be treated as general-purpose row identifiers, as they can be changed by various internal operations, but they should be stable as long as you hold a lock on the row.

Comment: I discovered there was another function that was updating tuples that never appeared in the error logs.  That function was updated to access tuples in the same order as all other functions.

The point you make about only affecting tuples that are locked is a good one (that I missed) so I also updated the function to only deletes tuples that were locked.  Thanks for your time and effort the deadlocks are now gone.